# singleton in spark scala in map

Tags: scala, apache-spark

i have a usecase where i need to write to postgres database from spark ,

i have read the incoming file to a rdd, my final result is a rdd that i can write to postgres.Inside the rdd map function I am trying to create the jdbc template and write to postgres.I want my jdbc template as singleton and i have made the jdbctemplate as Object.But still it seems to be not working and opening too many connections.

```
rddToPostgres.map(postgresdata => toPostgresDatabase(r))




toPostgresDatabase(postgresdata:Row) {

var dataToLoad = new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("Nifi_Param",postgresdata.getAs("Nifi_Param")

var insertStatement = "insert in to postgresschema.nifitab(nifi_param) values(:nifi_param)"

new JdbcTemplate().getJdbcConn().update(insertStatement,dataToLoad)

}
```

}

```
Object JdbcTemplate(){


def getJdbcConn() {

new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(new DriverManagerDataSource().setDriverClassName().setPassword("XXXXX").setUsername("XXXXX"));
}
```

although JdbcTemplate is singleton since it is defined Object this is being called multiple times,can someone suggest  how to create singleton in scala and to use it inside rdd.map?

Answer (score 0):

Because `getJdbcConn` is a function (`def`), it is evaluated every time it's called.  If you make it a `val` it will only be evaluated once.

Additionally, there's no need to instantiate an object via `new`.

```
object JdbcTemplate {
  val jdbcConnection = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(new DriverManagerDataSource().setDriverClassName().setPassword("....").setUsername("....")
}

rddToPostgres.map { postgresData: Row =>
  val dataToLoad = new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("Nifi_Param", postgresData.getAs("Nifi_Param"))
  val insertStatement = "insert in to postgresschema.nifitab(nifi_param) values(:nifi_param)"

  JdbcTemplate.jdbcConnection.update(insertStatement, dataToLoad)
}
```